# ajaxstart is triggered in a toggle() event but Cant triger ajaxstop on Complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a function that handles toggle for a div that is triggered by clicking on some toggle button.

```
$('.r_eply_togler').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var nw_id = '#q_reply_form_' + id;
   $(nw_id).toggle();

  });
```

I have another function with  ajaxstart and ajaxstop to show loading during an ajax call.

```
function ajaxcompleted(){
  $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
  $('#spinner').show();
}); 

   $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    $('#spinner').hide();
    }); 
   }
```

However i do not want the ajaxstart and ajaxstop to be triggered when the toggle button is clicked. At the moment the ajaxcompleted function is being trigered on clicking the toggle button but not corectly since it does not stop i am guessing it because no ajax call is happening at that time.

Is there a way i can avoid triggering the ajaxcompleted function when toggle button is clicked or is there a way i can have it functioning correctly that is showing the loading more then hiding as it should.

**SOLUTION**

I have got the solution. I added return false in the toggle function and it worked. The problem was that there was no way for the ajaxCompelted() function to identify end of toggle event execution.

```
function togle(){
      $('.r_eply_togler').click(function() {
           var id = $(this).attr('id');
           var nw_id = '#q_reply_form_' + id;
           $(nw_id).toggle();
            return false;
          });   
    }
```

Thanks guys for the responses.

Comment: I wonder where is `.toggle()` & `.ajaxCompelted()` connected in the code what you have posted . could you post complete code

Comment: The rest of the code would be irrelevant in this case. That is the problem, That the ajaxcompleted() is connected by default to all jquery events. But i do not want it to affect the toggle event.

Comment: `Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none are in progress, jQuery triggers the ajaxStart event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxStart() method are executed at this time.` ref:http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Check the solution in edited question.

Comment: ok cool, add this solution as a answer and check it as Answer, so that this question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Hye you can use this for your solution
http://jqueryui.com/toggle/

Comment: post your answer as the solution then @jmsiox